# Browser back-button in AJAX problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I try to enable a brwoserback button for my tabs. But the problem is that in some cases the the hash dissapears.

```
function showTab1(){
    window.location.hash = 'tab1';
    oldHash = window.location.hash;
    //showTab1
}
function showTab2(){
    window.location.hash = 'tab2';
    oldHash = window.location.hash;
    //showTab2
}
function checkBrowserBackButtonInHome(){

    setInterval(function(){
        if(window.location.hash != oldHash) {
            //Do something
        }
    }, 50);
} 
showTab1();
```

and than I click on showTab2. And when I click on the browser back button the hash dissapears. `index.php` instead of `index.php#tab1`

EDIT:

It seems like this only happens in chrome web browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this instead of the interval:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
  //Do something
});
```

Comment: Can I set in the server side the hashtag I think that is the problem? I'm using PHP

Comment: No with PHP you have no access to the hash tag. What you can do is put javascript first thing in your file. window.location.hash = what_you_want. This way it will always be there and mimic being put there with PHP

Comment: ok fixed it. I had an anchor with href='index.php' instead it should be href='index.php#tab1'

Comment: glad to hear.. you should probably still use the jQuery listener because it will be more efficent.